# How to resume my game after call ended

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have developed a game. When i checked in iphone, i found that my game pause when an incoming call comes and restarts after attending and ending the call. How to make it resume instead of restart

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the AppDelegate.m for this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}
```

That usually "pauses" the current scene when the application is interupted...say for a phone call. 
If this doesn't help...maybe you could eyplain your problem further.
greetings